# How to parse a string and transform it into a sequence in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have a string that looks like this `[abc, def, ghi]`

I want to parse the string and convert it to a sequence such that it is like this `Seq(abc, def, ghi)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi is the string contained in a DataFrame? Or how does Spark come into play?

If it's just plain scala, this should do the trick:

```
val string = "[abc, def, ghi]"
string
.replace("[", "")
.replace("]", "")
.split(",")
.map(_.trim)
.toSeq
```